# Trying to add UTF-8 compatibility to existing config files

Tags: utf-8

First question for me here, so please bear with me.

I'm working with some software that uses proprietary config files (think INI files).  These files are loaded in on program startup and the data is used during runtime.  The data can be changed during runtime, and the config files themselves are updated on program shutdown.

We have been adding new language support to our software, and have run into a problem.  When we give data to these config files at runtime that contain non-ASCII characters, the config files don't recognize them correctly because they aren't UTF-8 compatible.

I've attempted to modify the creation of the FILE objects that get filled out on startup to use the ccs=UTF-8 mode, and I've also tried to do a _setmode(_fileno(fin), _O_U8TEXT); call after the FILE stream has been opened, but both attempts cause the following assertion:

```
File: fgets.c
Line: 75

Expression: ( (_Stream->_flag & _IOSTRG) || 
((_textmode_safe(_fileno(_Stream)) == _IOINFO_TM_ANSI) && 
!_tm_unicode_safe(_fileno(_Stream))))
```

What is even stranger is that this assertion seems to be stemming from the

```
_VALIDATE_STREAM_ANSI_SETRET(stream, EINVAL, retval, NULL);
```

line in fgets.c, which is surrounded by an #ifndef _UNICODE block, and I have _UNICODE defined for my project.

Any insight into resolving this issue so that I can have UTF-8 compatibility through _setmode or the ccs mode flag would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on the Windows platform? If so, I'm wondering whether you might consider converting the UTF-8 back and forth to/from whatever encoding Windows uses rather than trying to get the configuration files to handle UTF-8 properly.